How to search for a file with a filename consisting of multiple words only via the first letters of the words in VSCode?
In VSCode you can search and open files via the "Go to file" option (Ctrl+P).
Can I configure VSCode somehow to be able to, e.g. find the file AppServiceProvider.php with the search: ASP?
I tried to find a solution for this is the configuration options of VSCode and searched on Google but wasn't be able to find something.

Does changing the setting Workbench > List: Default Find Match Type to fuzzy make any difference?

it should already behave like this. if it doesn't for you, something is wrong.

The Default Find Match Type is already fuzzy. It is in fact behaving like this, but the editor's approach is really stupid. I opened the AppServiceProvider.php multiple times, more often then any other suggested file for the ASP search term. Additionally it searches the whole vendor folder (php composer), which is good and I want, but maybe that is another problem why it does not show up. But same result for every other possible "shortcut" search for any other files I open all the time in this project.

read https://stackoverflow.com/q/75954434/11107541

Unfortunatly this does not help with the initial problem, that the file does not even show up, because literally hundreds of files are matching ASP, alone because most files end with .php. So I cannot even "train" it to open the correct file.

Sublime Text 3 did this without any problem at all. I did not even need to train it really. It just showed the file as one of the firsts, because it was "smart" and did notice, that A(pp)S(ervice)P(rovider).php does match perfectly.

When I just enter A it works and shows the AppServiceProvider.php, but as soon as I enter AS it shows hundreds of totally irrelevant files, I never opened once. It would be fine If I only had literally one "important" file starting with A, but obviously that is not the case.
